# Why is "desperacy" not an English word?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, is-it-a-word, figures-of-speech

I know one says *an act of desperation*, but I've heard *desperacy* much more than I've ever heard *desperation*, it's like I've almost never heard *desperation*.

Why exactly was *desperation* preferred over *desperacy* and **is there a pattern to noun adjectives ending with *-ate*?**

Comment: Whereabouts did you hear it, and how do they pronounce it? DESP'raCEE? DesPAIR-uh-cy? Desp-uh-RAYcy?

Comment: ***desperacy*** desperation  *desperate* + *-cy* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desperacy

Comment: It ain't cause it ain't.

Comment: @MrLister it is /dɛspərəsi/

Comment: @Mitch of course, it's not because it's not but you're forgetting the second part of my question.

Comment: I'd give the same answer. I've never heard your word. Also, I see no motivation for the possibility of your alternate. Can you give an explanation as to how your word is commonly an alternate (in other situations re '-ation' and '-cy'? That is to say, you're presuming that we understand the situation you see, but at least I am not seeing it.

Comment: Google Books returns 163 results for *desperacy*. "The Danes every where defended themselves with uncommon bravery and desperacy, as they had every thing to apprehend from the enraged assailants."

Comment: What Mitch says in his comment, and what tchrist explains in his answer, is a very basic morphological principle called [blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28linguistics%29).

Comment: "I've heard desperacy much more than I've ever heard desperation"  What speech community have you heard this in? English is spoken in many varieties around the world, and it may be that you've heard it in a place that uses slightly different rules for derivation than the standard dialects.

Comment: I'd bet a dollar the OP has heard "disparity", not "desperacy". Or that it is an ESL usage.

Comment: [Desperacy](http://0-www.oed.com.iii.slcl.org/view/Entry/50954?redirectedFrom=desperacy&) is a word, albeit obselete.

Answer (score 7):

I wonder where the OP has heard *desperacy* much more than *desperation*.

The OED says:

> **desperacy**, *n.*  *Obs.*

> Etymology:  < **desperate** *adj., n.*, and *adv.*: see **‑acy** *suffix.*

> Desperateness, desperation.

> - **1629** J. Gaule *Practique Theories Christs Predict.* 11
>   Downe to the nethermost depth beyond recouerie: Let vs there take our portion of desperacie.

- **1798** *Ann. Reg.* (Otridge ed.) *Hist. Europe* 155/2
  Such deeds of desperacy and revenge.
- **1800** W. E. J. *Obi* 231
  Deeds of desperacy and cruelty.

which suggest that it was a used word, about two centuries ago. [Ngram can find no example](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desperacy&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), nor can [Google Books](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/x.asp), nor can [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).

It is not that that *desperacy* is not an English word. It is not a current English word.

Comment: You’re right: I was discounting the obsoleted words by default.

Answer (score 5):

***Desperacy*** is “not a word”<sup>1</sup> because just plain ***despair*** alone plenty suffices as a noun, without any redundantly tedious nominalizationalizing suffixes and postfixes and add-on-the-enders.

The take-away lesson here is that sometimes, perhaps even often, it is far better to trim things off instead of tack them on.

---

1. <sub>That is, not a word attested<sup>2</sup> by the *Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>
2. <sub>That is, not a word attested as being current in **contemporary** English. 
   However, the *OED* does attest an **obsolete** word **†ˈ*desperacy***,
   and for which it provides no citation later than from the 18<sup>th</sup> century.</sub>

---

As for the second part of your question, here are some attested triples that may interest you:

- adequacy, adequate, adequation
- advocacy, advocate, advocation
- alternacy, alternate, alternation
- articulacy, articulate, articulation
- automacy, automate, automation
- complicacy, complicate, complication
- confederacy, confederate, confederation
- conjugacy, conjugate, conjugation
- degeneracy, degenerate, degeneration
- delegacy, delegate, delegation
- determinacy, determinate, determination
- effeminacy, effeminate, effemination
- episcopacy, episcopate, episcopation
- illegitimacy, illegitimate, illegitimation
- inadequacy, inadequate, inadequation
- inarticulacy, inarticulate, inarticulation
- inchoacy, inchoate, inchoation
- indeterminacy, indeterminate, indetermination
- inebriacy, inebriate, inebriation
- inordinacy, inordinate, inordination
- intermediacy, intermediate, intermediation
- intestacy, intestate, intestation
- intimacy, intimate, intimation
- itineracy, itinerate, itineration
- legitimacy, legitimate, legitimation
- lunacy, lunate, lunation
- numeracy, numerate, numeration
- obduracy, obdurate, obduration
- oracy, orate, oration
- prelacy, prelate, prelation
- privacy, private, privation
- profligacy, profligate, profligation
- prolificacy, prolificate, prolification
- regeneracy, regenerate, regeneration
- reprobacy, reprobate, reprobation
- subordinacy, subordinate, subordination
- surrogacy, surrogate, surrogation
- testacy, testate, testation
- ultimacy, ultimate, ultimation
- unregeneracy, unregenerate, unregeneration

Comment: +1 for nominalizationalizing. I had always thought that was spelled nominalizationalitizing.

Comment: Interesting that in several cases both the noun forms are common and mean different things (dengeneracy/degeneration; illegitimacy/illegitimation; intimacy/intimation; numeracy/numeration; privacy/privation; and probably others)

Comment: There is a significant difference between despair and desperation. Despair is a paralyzing grief. Desperation is a "nothing left to lose" willingness for extreme acts. While they both refer to a similar situation (dire hopelessness), they describe quite opposite attitudes. I wonder where would that put desperacy on the scale.